# What does MISSING_TARGET means on Amazon DMS (Database Migration Service) validation?

Tags: migration, amazon-dms

I'm running Amazon DMS from RDS to Aurora, the error when full restarting (never been successful before) from `awsdms_validation_failures_v1` tables are:

```json
[
  {
    "TASK_NAME": "TPPHLQOQH3WTSU27DVRVWS2BAXTQ7E7DYITWJCQ",
    "TABLE_OWNER": "public",
    "TABLE_NAME": "fraud_info",
    "FAILURE_TIME": "2021-10-20 13:20:13.031174",
    "KEY_TYPE": "Row",
    "KEY": "{\n\t\"key\":\t[\"9990\"]\n}",
    "FAILURE_TYPE": "MISSING_TARGET"
  }
]
```

when I query from information schema on target database, it does exists

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name   = 'fraud_info'
;
```

What does it means?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I really want to like the DMS offering but finding out what these errors means is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

I read on another [blog](https://www.sentiatechblog.com/aws-database-migration-service-dms-tips-and-tricks) that reloading the offending table would solve this problem.  I reloaded the tables I was having problems with and they validated the second time.

If that fails, you can try to truncate the target table manually and re-load it from the DMS console.  For some reason, my target table had a lot more records in it than my source table (100k more).  I logged into the target RDS instance and truncated the table.  When I reloaded the table everything worked properly and all the records validated.